# How can I select a JSON_VALUE if the object name contains a single quote?

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016-express

I am trying to get a value from some JSON in a table. This is my query:

```
Select JSON_VALUE(JSON_Data, '$.Person's_ID') FROM Table
```

To try and get the value for Person's Id. This is (part of) the JSON stored in the JSON_Data column:

```
"Person's_ID": "Test"
```

I have tried using two single quotes but this still gives an error:

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ''' is found at position 8."

Using a backslash to escape the single quote also does not work.

Comment: Use two `'`s to escape the character `Person''s_ID`

Comment: If you select the whole JSON value, how does this field appear?

Comment: @Charleh The OP indicated in the question that they already tried that and it didn't work. This is an invalid character according to the JSON parser, not anything to do with delimiting strings (well, you need to double up to handle replacements, but that doesn't fix the parsing issue).

Comment: @JoshPart exactly as I have posted above

Comment: @AaronBertrand ah yeah, valid JSON, wasn't really looking at the JSON issue and somehow missed the comment at the bottom. Tired probably, and I think I was doubly confused as to why someone with 1,600 rep would be struggling with escaping a single quote :D

Answer (score 5):

This might be a good lesson to not make garbage JSON (and validate it before inserting it into the database) since, [according to the standard](http://www.json.org/), single quote is not an accepted character in an entity name. :-)

You could try this type of replacement, but performance is going to be pretty craptastic, and it will replace *all* instances of `Person's_ID`, not just when it appears as an object:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(JSON_Data,'Person''s_ID','Person_s_ID'), '$.Person_s_ID')
  FROM dbo.Table;
```

Working example:

```
DECLARE @d varchar(255) = '{"Person''s_ID": "Test"}';
SELECT JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(@d,'Person''s','Person_s'), '$.Person_s_ID');
```

Result:

```
Test
```